# How to mirror/proxy a website?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project where I want to mirror a website. The idea is (my test case), that the original website won't be able to track user clicks and ad clicks.

What I found so far is this [guide/repository on GitHub](https://github.com/greatfire/website-mirror-by-proxy).

**I am running an EC2 instance with Ubuntu on AWS.**

> My question is now: How can I mirror a website and how does it
>   actually work?

Comment: You are asking for a solution without providing much specifics. How is the original server set up?

Answer (score 0):

- To mirror means that you'll retrieve all websites pages (or a subset you care about) in another machine that you own. Here you probably will have a webserver installed that serves the pages you mirrored, and clients must connect to your website, not the original one.
- To proxy it means that you configure a proxy software (apache, nginx, squid, varnish, whatever) in your server. In this case too, clients must connect to your server and your server transparently passes the request to the origin server and back to the client, optionally storing a cached copy for later reuse.

Now, if you want to mirror it, the first thing that comes to my mind is `wget`, for more info check this reply: https://superuser.com/questions/352397/download-entire-site-for-offline-usage-with-wget-including-external-image-serve

If you want to reverse proxy it, the how depends on the software you'll use.

Beware of javascripts / Flash embedded in the original website, there could be XHR requests or similar that point to the original site with obvious privacy / security considerations.